# How can I get data from a JSON url?

Tags: javascript, json

https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/top/.json?sort=top&t=day

I have this url that has the JSON data from a website. I would like to retrieve, for instance, the url to the first linked image from this webpage.

this is the code I have so far

```
var jsonURL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/top/.json?sort=top&t=day";
loadJSON(jsonURL);

function logData()
{
    console.log(data.children[0].preview.images.source.url);
}
```

The current error I have is "Uncaught ReferenceError: loadJSON is not defined" I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as I have p5.js in the directory that I'm working in, but also I feel like I'm completely misunderstanding the syntax of json. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) I would expect `loadJSON` to be an asynchronous function so you would need to take that into account 2) You're not calling `logData` anywhere.

Comment: The error just says that the loadJSON function doesn't exist. Check that your script is loaded after the necessary reference and you loaded the reference correctly. Else try it with jquery $.ajax or $.get

Comment: Well, [here's the documentation for p5,js](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON). Maybe try an follow this once you've gotten the script to load properly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you are not calling `logData`. Also if you were calling it the output you are logging doesn't look like it would return any results.

I have it working using `fetch` you don't need to depend on jQuery for this.

```js
var jsonURL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/top/.json?sort=top&t=day";
loadJSON(jsonURL);

function logData(data){
  console.log(data.data.children[0].data.preview.images[0].source.url)
}

function loadJSON(url) {
  fetch(url)
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        logData(data)
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
}
```

Comment: The OP is using `p5,js`. Might be worth reading the question again.